# Compress JPEG image with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to resize and compress an uploaded image from the user, but when I upload a JPEG image I get a result similar to this. PNG format seems to work just fine, does anyone has any idea what is going on here? I tried a different compression and all resampling types but it doesn't help either.

```
image = Image.open(image_path)
image.thumbnail((1000, 1000), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image.save(target_path, 'JPEG', quality=90, optimize=True)
```

#### Environment

- CentOS 6 64bit
- Pillow 2.8.1

[image]

Comment: have you tried: 1) different images? 2) different settings (optimize=False) ? what is the version of PIL / python ?

Comment: I tried a few images, with and without optimize, still same

Comment: incompatible jpeg DLL ?